# flutter moor - update only specified columns without custom query

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-moor

I want to update only specified columns, when I execute `update(table).replace(model)` it replaces all data corresponding to primary key. How to update only specified column without writing custom queries.

Comment: you can update based on their id.

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare your function with `Insertable` like that:

```
Future updateVisit(Insertable<Visit> visit) => update(visits).replace(visit);
```

so, when you call a function  you can do this:

```
visitDao.updateVisit(visit.copyWith(completed: newValue))
```

or

```
visitDao.updateVisit(VisitsCompanion(id: Value(visitId), checkOut: Value(DateTime.now())));
```

Comment: this doesn't answer his question. I need the same answered

Answer (score 2):

In the docs, I found this that might be helpful, depending on your use case. This is how you could [replace values of a single column.](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/writing_queries/#updates-and-deletes)

```
   Future moveImportantTasksIntoCategory(Category target) {
     // for updates, we use the "companion" version of a 
     generated class. This wraps the
     // fields in a "Value" type which can be set to be absent using "Value.absent()". This
     // allows us to separate between "SET category = NULL" 
    (`category: Value(null)`) and not
    // updating the category at all: `category: Value.absent()`.

    return (update(todos)
     ..where((t) => t.title.like('%Important%'))
      ).write(TodosCompanion(
      category: Value(target.id),
     ),
   );
 }
```